# Android - Eclipse (layout for presenting cards)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to present cards inside a layout that present dealer/player cards on a blackjack game. On java it's easy because there is a flowLayout, buy on android I don't know how to do it correctly. I thought maybe an horizontal layout would do that work? What do you think?

Comment: I would recommend reading into layouts on android. but yes a horizontal orientation would work.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. In the meantime can you tell me how can I refresh my activity? Because after a card being present, I need it to update all the data, like hand value (shown as string) and more staff.